# Type errors from imported dependency

Tags: typescript, npm, tsconfig

I'm looking for a help with understanding typescript compilation.

I'm importing typescript source code from node_modules dependency. Unfortunatelly this dependency library has been written with less strict typescript compiling settings. When I imported it to my project typescript is throwing errors from this dependency. Is it possible to skip or not throw errors from dependency?

Is there some typescript compiler sttings that will skip checking source code from depending library?

Comment: "my project typescript is throwing errors from this dependency" What is the error? Are you sure it's the dependencies fault? It's hard to tell exactly what is going wrong from your post. If you could [edit] your question to include [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would be a big help.